# Imshow in Matlab returns black image

Tags: matlab, rgb, satellite

I want to display a satellite image (16bit) that contains 4 bands with intensity levels: red, greens, blue and nir. However, I just want to display the first 3 bands. I use the following code:

```
RGB=imread('IMG_PHR1B_MS_202106020751594_ORT_5893575101-2_R1C1.TIF');
subset_RGB=RGB(1550:3238,343:1250,1:3);
figure(1)
imshow(subet_RGB)
impixelinfo
```

The pixels show clearly different values, but the image is completely black.
values range from:

red: 473-4152

green:599-4256

blue:507-3737

I transformed this image to HSV (because I also need this).

```
normal=im2double(subset_RGB);
hsv=rgb2hsv(normal);
imshow(hsv)
```

This image does result in a colour image.
I maybe thought it was because hsv is double and subset_RGB is 16-bit. so I tried the following:

```
test=im2double(subset_RGB)
imshow(test)
```

I also tried imagesc as suggested, but results in black image:

```
figure(2)
imagesc(subset_RGB)
```

How can I display the original image in true colours?

Comment: Is the range of pixel values in your image from 0 to 255?

Comment: Try `imagesc`? This scales the image before displaying it.

Comment: I edited the post with both sugestions.

Comment: Use `imshow(subet_RGB,[])`.

Comment: According to the documentation here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.image-properties.html

your color triplet values should range from [0 255] but you say your values range from far outside that range. Are they getting scaled later?

Answer (score 1):

To display an RGB image using `imshow`, you have to rescale it from 0 to 255. I do not know what is the original bit depth of your image (even though it is saved with 16 bits, the actual bit depth may be smaller). I will assume it is 13 bits, as it is the next power of two higher than the values you have shown.

```matlab
rescaled_img = uint8(double(subset_RGB) / (2^(13-8)));
imshow(rescaled_img);
```

Note that the colours may be off or too dark if the bit depth is wrong. An alternative, instead of dividing by `8192`, you can divide by the maximum in the image. In that case, use:

```matlab
rescaled_img = uint8(256 * double(subset_RGB) / max(subset_RGB, [], 'all'));
imshow(rescaled_img);
```

Comment: Correct, fixed it!